# update multiple values in nested array within another array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection in mongodb:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("001"),
"car" : [
    {
        "name" : "v02hf31",
        
    }
],

"brand" : [
    {
        "name" : [
            {
                "type" : "Ford"
            },
            {
                "color" : "black"
            }
        ],
```

I need to update color in nested array brand to blue in all documents in the collection. I tried this:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{ 
    "brand.name.color" : "black"}, 


{ "$set": {"brand.$[].name.$[e].color":"blue"}},
{
    arrayFilters: [{"e.color":"black"}]
}
```

)

I get this error: "Unrecognized field in update operation: arrayFilters". "FailedToParse"

How can I update a value in array within another array for all documents?

Update: I tried this query

```
  db.collection.updateOne(
    {
        
        "brand": {
            "name" : {
            "$elemMatch": {
                 "color": "black"
            }
          }
        }
    },
    { "$set": { 
        "brand.name.$.color": "blue"
    } }
    );
```

I'm not getting error message after running this query but I'm not having the value updated either.

Comment: [Tested your query seems works fine](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ExBQKBvj6Yk).

Comment: @YongShun It throws this error for me: "Unrecognized field in update operation: arrayFilters"

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: @ray it says server version: 3.4.17

Comment: That's a very old version. `arrayFilters` are only available for [MongoDB version 3.6+](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

Comment: @ray I used this query without arrayFilters. executed with no errors but value isn't updated either.  db.collection.updateOne(
    {
        
        "brand": {
            "name" : {
            "$elemMatch": {
                 "color": "black"
            }
          }
        }
    },
    { "$set": { 
        "brand.name.$.color": "blue"
    } }
    );